# How do I print TCL environment variable in my bash script

Tags: bash, tcl

TCL script

```
set ::env(foo) "bar"
```

bash script

```
echo ${env(foo)}
echo $foo
```

I am able to print the environment variable in the TCL script but for some reason I can't print the environment variable in my bash script. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the relationship between the two scripts?

Comment: If `foo` is in the environment of your shell, it's simply `echo "$foo"`. On startup, the shell simply defines a regular shell variable for each name in the environment that forms a valid shell identifier.

Comment: Following up Shawn's comment: if you're invoking the Tcl script from your shell, and you expect the env var to appear in your shell, it can't happen -- a child process is not allowed to alter the environment of its parent.

Answer (score 2):

If your bash script contains something like this (let's call it `showenv`)

```
#! /bin/bash

echo $foo
```

and your tcl

```
#! /usr/bin/tclsh

set ::env(foo) bar

exec ./showenv >>& /dev/tty
```

then, `showenv` will show

```
bar
```

that is, the tcl script sets the environment for its children processes.

Comment: Environment variables _never_ automatically go the other way, from child to parent. Instead, one has to write something (to standard out or to a file) that the caller interprets as an instruction to set an environment variable